# default schema name in netezza query log

Tags: database, logging, schema, default, netezza

I am looking for default schema name using which a particular query has been executed(if table name is not fully qualified).In Netezza all the logged queries get stored in  histDb, where I can find out the default database for the logged queries, however I am not able to get default database against queries.
I can get default schema for any database in '_V_database' meta data view.But user can change the default schema before executing any query using 'Set schema command'.
I want to know information about default schema under which a query has been run.

Answer (score 0):

If your system is configured to use schemas *and* your history database is of the proper version (v2 or v3) to support recording the schema, you can find the schema to which a given query was connected when it ran.

Look for the SCHEMANAME column in the $hist_query_prolog_n (e.g. for version 3, this will be $hist_query_prolog_3 )table in your history database.  [This is documented thoroughly here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/r_sysadm_hist_query_prolog_schema.html).

Remember that you need to quote the history table names in your queries.

```
select schemaname from "$hist_query_prolog_3"  where querytext like 'select count(1)%';
 SCHEMANAME 
------------
 SCHEMA_A
 SCHEMA_B
 SCHEMA_A
 SCHEMA_A
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Thank You for the response.I will check it.

Comment: So we don't have any information about schema if hist version is 1?

Comment: That's correct.  You would need to switch to a version 2 or 3 of the history database to track schema information for your queries.